# Are these list-comprehensions written the fastest possible way?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

This is a simple repeatable question regarding the usage of Python3's comprehensions:

**Could the Python3 syntax be used in another way to speed up the process, further so the gap between Python3 and numpy would be reduced?** (see chart below).

The results & code:
[image: Runtime test of Python3's list comprehension, dict comprehension, python for loop and numpy]
Above: Runtime test of Python3's list comprehension, dict comprehension, python for loop and numpy
[image: Runtime test without power-functions including Janne Karila suggestion to break down the power function to x * x * x]
**Update 1** Above: Runtime test without power-functions including Janne Karila suggestion to break down the power function to x * x * x
[image: Runtime test without powerfunctions and with Justin Peels recommendation to use return list(a.values())]
**Update2** Above: Runtime test without powerfunctions and with Justin Peels recommendation to use return list(a.values())

```
#/usr/bin/python3 -


import sys
from datetime import datetime
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def doingnothing(n):
    for i in range(n):
        pass
    return []

def numpysum(n): #NPY
    a = numpy.arange(n) ** 2.
    b = numpy.arange(n) ** 3.
    c = a + b
    return c

def listexpression(n):  #LE
    #return [x**2+x**3 for x in range(n)]
    return [x*x+x*x*x for x in range(n)]

def dictcomprehension(n):  #DC
    # a = {x:x**2+x**3 for x in range(n)}
    a = {x:x*x+x*x*x for x in range(n)}
    # return [a[key] for key in a]
    return list(a.values())

def pythonsum(n): #PS
    a = list(range(n))
    b = list(range(n))
    c = []

    for i in range(len(a)):
            # a[i] = i ** 2.
            a[i] = i * i 
            # b[i] = i ** 3.
            b[i] = i * i * i
            c.append(a[i] + b[i])
    return c

def runtimetest(size,verbose=True):
    v = verbose
    d = {'DoingNothing':None,
         'NPY':None,
         'LE':None,
         'DC':None,
         'PS':None}

    start = datetime.now()
    c = doingnothing(size)
    d['DoingNothing'] = datetime.now() - start

    start = datetime.now()
    c = numpysum(size)
    d['NPY'] = datetime.now() - start

    start = datetime.now()
    c = listexpression(size)
    d['LE'] = datetime.now() - start

    start = datetime.now()
    c = dictcomprehension(size)
    d['DC'] = datetime.now() - start

    start = datetime.now()
    c = pythonsum(size)
    d['PS'] = datetime.now() - start

    if v:
        for key in sorted(d):
            print(key, "took", round(d[key].seconds + d[key].microseconds/10**6,6), " sec.")
    else:
        return d

def view(results):
    """
    result['header']=['DoingNothing','NPY','LE','DC','PS']
    result[3000]=[0.0, 0.0, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003001] 
    """
    if 'header' in results.keys():
        results.pop('header')

    steps,DN,NPY,LE,DC,PS=[],[],[],[],[],[] #I love multiple assignment!

    for step in sorted(results):
        steps.append(step)
        DN.append(results[step][0])
        NPY.append(results[step][4])
        LE.append(results[step][5])
        DC.append(results[step][6])
        PS.append(results[step][4])

    pyplot.plot(steps,DN)
    pyplot.plot(steps,NPY)
    pyplot.plot(steps,LE)
    pyplot.plot(steps,DC)
    pyplot.plot(steps,PS)
    pyplot.legend(['Empty Loop', 'Numpy.Arange', 'List Comprehension', 'Dict Comprehension', 'Python for Loop'], loc='upper left')
    scale = 'linear'
    pyplot.xscale(scale)
    pyplot.yscale(scale)
    pyplot.title('runtime test')
    pyplot.xlabel('length of list')
    pyplot.ylabel('runtime in seconds')

    pyplot.show()

def longruntimetest(length):
    if length<10**4:
        length=10**4

    result = {}
    result['header']=['DoingNothing','NPY','LE','DC','PS']
    for step in range(10**3, length+1,10**3):
        t=runtimetest(step,verbose=False)        
        result[step]=[t['DoingNothing'],t['NPY'],t['LE'],t['DC'],t['PS']]
        for i in range(len(result[step])):
            result[step][i]=round(result[step][i].seconds
                                  +result[step][i].microseconds/10**6,6)

    view(result)

def main():
    if sys.version_info <= (3, 2):
        sys.stdout.write("Sorry, requires Python 3.2.x, not Python 2.x\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    testsize=10**5
    runtimetest(testsize)   
    longruntimetest(testsize)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Similar, though not the same:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708783/numpy-vs-list-comprehension-which-is-faster?rq=1

Comment: You might also be able to speed up the `numpysum` function by calling `arange` only once (for me a factor of about .75).  `a = np.arange(n); c = a**2 + a**3`  Still, @Janne's solution helps even more.

Comment: @askewchan, or even better, do `a = np.arange(n); b = a * a; c = b + b * a`

Comment: in dictcomprehension, `return list(a.values())` is faster on my machine than the list comprehension you are using.

Comment: Why is pythonsum so convoluted? shouldn't it just be `for i in range(n): a = i * i; b = a * i; c.append(a + b` or something similar to that?

Comment: @Justin, for i in range(n) is correct, it cuts off the overhead for the len-function. But because a is a list b = a * i wont work.

Comment: why are `a` and `b` lists in the first place in that function?

Comment: The run-time test is about creating a comparable scenario's for all 5 numerical operations and measure the runtime.

Comment: okay. I just don't see them all as exactly comparable I guess.

Comment: ...Comparable as "producing the same result" using similar methods.

Comment: Exactly, a list comprehension is comparable to the method I described using a for loop... not to creating two extra lists `a` and `b`. Anyway, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def listexpression(n):  #LE
    return [x * x * (1 + x) for x in range(n)]
```

is over 3 times faster than your version with `x**2+x**3` (from 8.47 ms to 2.31 ms with n = 10000).

Though, NumPy will also benefit from regrouping the expression this way.

Comment: Is factoring like this generally beneficial?  What's so inefficient about the power syntax?

Comment: @askewchan, count the number of multiplies. x * x + x * x * x is 3 multiplies. x * x * (1 + x) is two multiplies and an addition. That doesn't account for the whole speed up but it is part of it. A multiply is generally much slower than an addition.

Comment: Oh I missed that point entirely, it really is the factoring (like I wrote but didn't realize).  So `x**2 * (1 + x)` would speed it up just as much.

Comment: @askewchan: no, `x*x` should be a little faster than `x**2` (although not by much given the Python overhead).  Basically, raising something to an arbitrary power has to go via logarithms or the equivalent behind the scenes, whereas `x*x` is just one float multiplication.  (Admittedly modern C compilers are pretty good at strength-reducing `pow` calls with hardcoded exponents, but if the value isn't known until runtime you often have to branch.)

Comment: I just timeit’d it: `x * x * (1 + x)` > `x * x + x * x * x` >> `x ** 2 * (1 + x)` >>> `x ** 2 + x ** 3` (`>` means a bit faster, `>>` quite a bit faster, `>>>` a lot faster).

Comment: Interestingly enough, instead of assuming, I also timeit'd it myself before I wrote that comment and found that `a*a*a*a*(1+a)` is 1.4% faster than `a**4 * (1+a)` on my machine, so clearly it is not always `>>` faster.  I suppose it's because it's a hard-coded exponent.

Comment: @askewchan, if you are going to do a**4 * (1+a), then you should do it as b=a*a and get b*b*(1+a) which saves you a multiply.

Comment: @askewchan: no, it's much likelier to be because each Python op is pretty slow.  Try `import dis` and then `dis.dis(lambda a: a*a*a*a*(1+a))` and `dis.dis(lambda a: a**4 * (1+a))`.  There are multiple factors at play: Python operation overhead; speed of multiplication vs exponentiation; there's even a difference between `x**4.0` and `x**4`.  There are a number of tradeoffs going on.

Comment: Cool - dis.dis(lambda ....) is very good input. Thanks

Comment: @askewchan You mean that it’s maybe not `>>` faster but just `>` faster? To be fair, that relation wasn’t supposed to be proportional or anything, just to show that the first are relative similar with a minor difference to the third and a larger difference to the last one.

Comment: From the Press et al., Numerical Recipes book, regarding polynomial evaluation: ["Come the (computer) revolution, all persons found guilty of such criminal behavior will be summarily executed, and their programs won’t be!"](http://numericalrecipes.wordpress.com/about/)